# Adding HTML link to a PHP message array

Tags: php, authentication, woocommerce

In the Woocommerce login module there is a piece of text that needs to be edited and a register link placed inside of the message. But if I just add in the HTML tags around the link then the code shows up in the text and not as a link.

This is the original code in the form-login.php file

```
'message'  => esc_html__( 'If you have shopped with us before, please enter your details below. If you are a new customer, please proceed to the Billing section.', 'woocommerce' ),
```

This is how I have changed it to include Register and the link:

```
'message'  => esc_html__( 'If you have shopped with us before, please enter your details below. If you are a new customer, please' . '<a href="#login" class="register-text">Register</a>' . ' to proceed.', 'woocommerce' ),
```

I also tried the following but it broke the site so not an option:

```
'message'  => esc_html__( 'If you have shopped with us before, please enter your details below. If you are a new customer, please' . '<a href="#login" class="register-text">Register</a>' . ' to proceed.', 'woocommerce' ),
```

I just need the word "Register" to become a link with a specific class for the color and hover (which is created in the CSS). How can I do this please?

Comment: `esc_html__()` __escapes html__.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**esc_html** *escapes* your HTML code, so
 `<a href="#login" class="register-text">Register</a>` becomes `&lt;a href=&quot;#login&quot; class=&quot;register-text&quot;&gt;Register&lt;/a&gt;`.

You'll need to remove the esc_html() function.

(Be careful with this though, as serving unescaped HTML could be dangerous if using dynamic content [Learn more...](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html))

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Nathan Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58361952). It took me a few tries, but I finally got it right. The final code looks as such:

```
'message'  => __( 'If you have shopped with us before, please enter your details below. If you are a new customer, please' . '<a href="#login" class="register-text"> Register</a>' . ' to proceed.', 'woocommerce' ),
```

I don't understand why the '__' needed to be there, but if I remove it then nothing worked, so I left it in.